# Left work and they would like to look at the personal emails

Tags: email, legal, law

Good morning All,

My basic question is: Is my former employer allowed legally to ask and search through my gmail/google-drive account?

I have recently changed jobs to a competitor and did upload some personal information to my google account. It did contain some very old files (2015) from the workplace, however it are not confidential files and they were uploaded by mistake.

I was about to let them search my google account and delete whatever they wanted to, since I don't have anything to hide. But I also thought I'd ask - because I might be acting a bit naive.

Should I talk to a lawyer first? are they allowed to even ask? are they allowed to search?

Thank you

Comment: We can't answer this question. If you want legal advice, you need to contact a lawyer. It will depend heavily on where you live, where you work, and what your contract says.

Comment: I would ignore such a ridiculous request by an ex-employer unless it comes with legal threats attached, and THEN I would seek legal advise.

Comment: They have full access to the emails you sent from your work account. They do not have access to your private email... are they allowed to walk into your house?

Comment: @chrismorrison, how does your employer know you've uploaded these (or any) files? Do they have records from their network monitoring tools? What's the point of them even asking to search your gmail/google-drive, when you could easily remove any offending emails/files before they search?

Comment: True, it could be removed before they searched. I had old personal files (diploma copies, and things of that nature that I uploaded before I left - when I handed the work laptop in they most likely saw it through their logs)

Comment: Why would you even consider giving them access? If you're in the USA, I'm pretty certain that a warrant and/or subpoena would be required. Contact an attorney and don't give them access to anything unless and until you do.

Comment: In addition, I'd strongly advise that in the future you keep your work and personal business separate. Do not ever use company assets to check your personal email, cloud storage, LinkedIn profile, Facebook page, etc., etc.

Comment: Once you've left you just ignore anything that doesn't confer something positive for you.

Comment: @joeqwerty, generously reasonable usage of gmail, linkedIn, banking, facebook and other common stuff is almost universally tolerated in normal workplaces. If it was truly a problem wouldn't these things just be blocked?

Comment: Why are they asking this? What did you admit to them? Do they know you're working for a competitor?

Comment: @teego1967, whether it's almost universally tolerated or not is besides my point. I would never mix the two, precisely for the reason the OP lays out in his question.

Comment: the simple answer here is ghost them. ***DO NOT*** reply in ***ANY WAY***.

Comment: If you uploaded work files, you haven't deleted them yet yourself why?

Comment: The problem is you do in fact have company files on your personal account. I would delete said files and send a certified letter to your employer that you deleted the files and as far as you know, do not have access to anything. They could sue if they have proof you accessed files or previous POCs, and your lifeline will be that certified letter.

Answer (score 24):

No, don't **ever** give them access to your personal account.

If they have *specific* emails they want deleted, then they can inform you and you can do it yourself.

If they want to *watch* you deleting said emails and showing that you haven't forwarded them somewhere else, less reasonable but I'd probably just go with it.

If they want you to sign a document affirming that you haven't retained any copies of any documents from those specific emails, you should read it carefully and consult a lawyer if you want to, but probably also ok.

But giving them their own access? Not going to happen.

Comment: That does seem more reasonable than giving access. thank you

Comment: "and delete whatever they wanted to" --> they just delete everything

Comment: "If they want to watch you deleting..." This will just make him incriminate himself. I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I don't see how. Either they know which emails were sent to you or they don't. If they do, then letting them watch as you delete them doesn't give them any new information.

Comment: @Kaz, He's talking about files he uploaded to his google drive account. They'll just record his screen or testify to what they saw on his screen and then potentially use that as an excuse to sue their competitor. As to signing to documents, he should not sign anything unless there is something in it that's beneficial to him.

Answer (score 10):

> My basic question is: Is my former employer allowed legally to ask and search through my gmail/google-drive account?

They can ask for whatever they want.  You can politely decline.

Under no circumstances should you give them access to your personal account.

If they have a legal basis to pursue this matter, they will reach out to you with lawyers.  At that point, your best course of action would be to seek legal counsel.

Comment: The thing is, I do have some files, they aren't confidential information -  but I also don't want it to be misinterpreted as I am stealing information, even though the files are harmless they could construe it as such.

Comment: Downvoting this because it's essentially the same as the earlier answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm pretty sure this one was actually posted first.

Comment: SE says this is an hour old and yours 59 minutes.

Comment: @chrismorrison They know you uploaded the files to your personal account, and if they know that you are now working for a competitor they are very likely to misinterpret your intentions.

Comment: The problem is he uploaded company files into his personal account. I would say his employers could sue him for breach of the NDA since they could say he went to a competitor and used the files. If they have proof you accessed the file, they would have a valid suite. My advice is to not only delete the files but also send a certified letter as a precaution that you deleted all files and do not have any access that you know of. This will protect you if they decide to file a suite.